# Replace network address with host address in python

Tags: python, function, ip-address

Im having a file with ip address in this format

192.168.1.9

192.168.1.10

192.168.1.8

that i read to a list like this

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    ipaddr = f.read().splitlines()
```

And then run some functions on.

However, i would also be able to put in network address in this document as in
192.168.0.0/25 and somehow get them translated in the list as

192.168.0.1

192.168.0.2

192.168.0.3

I dont even have a clue how to accomplish this? (running Python 2.6)

Comment: Try the `netaddr` library: http://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/ . There are also alternatives to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`netaddr`](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/) is one of the best ways to do this:

```
import netaddr

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            ip_network = netaddr.IPNetwork(line.strip())
        except netaddr.AddrFormatError:
            # Not an IP address or subnet!
            continue
        else:
            for ip_addr in ip_network:
                print ip_addr
```

For the example file of:

```
10.0.0.1
192.168.0.230
192.168.1.0/29
```

The output it gives is:

```
10.0.0.1
192.168.0.230
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your text file with a regular expression. Look up for the 're' module in Python. A quick implementation of this idea is:

```
import re
with open("ips.txt") as f:
    ip_raw_list = f.read().splitlines()

#Only takes the string after the '/'
reg_ex_1 = r'(?<=/)[0-9]*'
#Only take the first three numbers "0.0.0" of the IP address
reg_ex_2 = r'.*\..*\..*\.' 
ip_final_list = list()

for ip_raw in ip_raw_list:

    appendix = re.findall(reg_ex_1, ip_raw)

    #Ip with no backslash create on input
    if not appendix:
        ip_final_list.append(ip_raw)

    #Ip with backslash create several inputs

    else:

        for i in range(int(appendix[0])):
            ip_final_list.append(re.findall(reg_ex_2, ip_raw)[0] + str(i))
```

This code uses the power of regular expression to separate IPs of the form '0.0.0.0' from IPs of the form '0.0.0.0/00'. Then for IPs of the first form, you put the IP directly on the final list. For IPs of the second for, you run a for loop to put several inputs in the final list.